# Vertically centering a div inside another div with unknown height in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[Sample Webpage](http://www.concordbuilders.com.php53-8.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/about/)

Please take a look at the above website. Is it possible to have the blocks of pictures always vertically centered inside their container?

In other words, having the div with the class of row-fluid vertically centered inside the div with the class of featured-projects.

Comment: you are using boots trap if you implement css on row-fluid class than it will effect other pages too

Comment: I can add additional classes to avoid messing with the bootstrap framework.

Comment: than make that class display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle;and dont float it

Comment: Please test your answer yourself too (in the developer tool or firebug). I've done that before with no success :-)

Answer (score 0):

To give the Css to row-fluid class & Give the height of the container.

**CSS**

```
.row-fluid {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Abd remove the **padding-top:2em** from featured-products class

Comment: but this is cutting off the featured-projects div short and it's not letting its background to continue all the way to the bottom of the page. You would notice this on big monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with table:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr><td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
    <div><img src="" /></div>
    <div><img src="" /></div>
    <div><img src="" /></div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```